# Why does $c_{1}\sin(x)+c_{2}\cos(x)=c_{1}e^{ix}+c_{2}e^{-ix}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

$y''+y=\tan(x)$ is a differential equation and the auxiliary equation is $r^{2}+1=0$. The auxiliary equation has solutions $i$ and $-i$ so the complementary solution is $c_{1}\cos(x)+c_{2}\sin(x)$. I tried to derive that from $c_{1}e^{ix}+c_{2}e^{-ix}$ and it's not working for me.

$c_{1}e^{ix}=c_{1}\cos(x)+c_{1}i\sin(x)$ and $c_{2}e^{-ix}=c_{2}\cos(x)-c_{2}i\sin(x)$, I am guessing the $\cos(x)$ term is from the real part of $\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ but I don't get where $\sin(x)$ is from.

Comment: are you studying differential equations? then please mention the relevant ode.

Comment: Hint: write $e^{ix}$ using sines and cosines, similar for $e^{-ix}.$ Now add and subtract.

Comment: It's not the same $c_1,\,c_2$ on both sides.

Comment: I don't get it the coefficients make them impossible to add and subtract

Comment: If $a\sin x+b\cos x=ce^{ix}+de^{-ix}$, you can find $c,\,d$ in terms of $a,\,b$ or vice versa. The real aim is to give two parametrizations of the same set of functions, namely the solutions of $y''=-y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using exponential form of sine and cosine you have:
$$c_1\sin x+c_2\cos x=c_1\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}+c_2 \dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2} $$
Now let
$$ A=\dfrac{c_1}{2i}+\dfrac{c_2}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad B=-\dfrac{c_1}{2i}+\dfrac{c_2}{2}  $$
You can express the initial formula as:
$$c_1\sin x+c_2\cos x=Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix} $$

**Edit**

We know $$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x $$
Hence
$$ e^{-ix}=\cos (-x)+i\sin (-x) =\cos x-i\sin x$$
It follows that
$$e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2\cos x \quad \text{and}\quad e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=2i\sin x  $$
From which we get the exponential form of sine and cosine.

Comment: If I start with $AB2cos(x)$ from rewriting $Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix}$ as $\sin$ and $\cos$ what substitution would I have to use?

Comment: @554nddthd Hi, maybe it is a matter of notation.  Since $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants, the author of the book named the new constans as the old ones.

Comment: @554nddthd $2AB \cos x$ is not equal to $Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix}$

Comment: $e^{ix}= \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ is not the right and $e^{-ix}=\cos(x)-i\sin(x)$ is not right??

Comment: @554nddthd Yes, this is Euler identity. I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Because why can't I use the Euler i.d.???

Comment: @554nddthd you can use it, I also used it. But what do you want to do precisely?

Comment: I've just been trying to get from the exponential to the trigonometric functions and finish with $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ as the coefficients... it is not that clear to me really.

Comment: @554nddthd To get the exponential form of sine and cosine write Euler identity and add and subtract with $e^{-ix}=\cos x-i\sin x$

Comment: @554nddthd I edited the answer, take a look

Comment: So I start with $Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix}=A\cos(x)+Ai\sin(x)+B\cos(x)-Bi\sin(x)$ I can't add or subtract those so do I make a new coefficient from A and B that is $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$? I practiced a lot but I didn't practice the substitutions so I just am not able to guess what it is!

Comment: @554nddthd note that you want to return to $c_1$ and $c_2$, so it must be: $A+B=c_2$ and $(A-B)i=c_1$